# Exception thrown: read access violation. **node** was 0xDDDDDDDD. occurred

Tags: c++

I have to make a binary search tree for an assignment and everything is good until I delete my tree. It could be a really simple mistake on my part, but I'm unsure how to fix it. Every time I run the program while including the code to delete the tree I get "Exception thrown: read access violation. **node** was 0xDDDDDDDD. occurred."

Here's the code for my trees:

```
Tree::Tree()
{
    head = NULL;
}

Tree::~Tree()
{
    deleteNodes(head);
}

string Tree::checkBalance()
{
    int lh;
    int rh;

    lh = height(head->leftBranch);
    rh = height(head->rightBranch);

    if (abs(lh - rh) <= 1)
        return "KEEP";
    else
        return "REMOVE";
}

int Tree::height(Node* node)
{
    //If tree empty
    if (node == NULL)
        return 0;

    //If not empty, find max height
    return 1 + max(height(node->leftBranch), height(node->rightBranch));
}

void Tree::addNum(int num)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node;
    newNode->myNum = num;
    newNode->leftBranch = NULL;
    newNode->rightBranch = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *cursor = head;
        bool foundSpot = false;

        while (!foundSpot)
        {
            if (num < cursor->myNum)
            {
                if (cursor->leftBranch != NULL)
                    cursor = cursor->leftBranch;
                else
                {
                    cursor->leftBranch = newNode;
                    foundSpot = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (cursor->rightBranch != NULL)
                    cursor = cursor->rightBranch;
                else
                {
                    cursor->rightBranch = newNode;
                    foundSpot = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Tree::deleteNodes(Node *node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    //Deletes subtrees
    deleteNodes(node->leftBranch);
    deleteNodes(node->rightBranch);

    //Deletes node
    delete node;
}
```

Any help on what'a causing this error would be appreciated. The problem code seems to be in deleteNodes(Node *node) when it tries to access deleteNodes(node->leftBranch);

And in case there are any questions on what the node code looks like, here it is:

```
struct Node
{
    int myNum;
    Node *leftBranch;
    Node *rightBranch;
};
```

Comment: DDDDD looks like a pattern put by you OS (or libc) to kill the content of buffers that are not initialized or freed. If you are using Linux, you may run valgrind to help you identify the problem

Comment: i suggest you use your debugger to look at the tree you built and verify that all looks good. If you have multiple left or right pointers pointing at the same node then bad things will happen

Comment: Do you ever call `deleteNodes` other than from the destructor? It keeps dangling pointers around, which isn't a problem if it's only called from the dtor but would be a problem otherwise.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the function that is using the Node object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the line of code with the problem. Debug the code in visual studio. The debugger will stop when it detects the crash. You can the use debugger to generate a callstack of where your code was when the error occurred.

I suspect in this case, you are accessing a pointer to already deleted memory. The debug heap is being helpful an setting the deleted memory to 0xdd.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: A general guide to fixing these kind of problems should reach a much wider audience than the OPs specific bug. The OP seems to like it.

Answer (score 0):

Your are trying to do operations on a pointer that has value equal to NULL. You may replace NULL with nullptr.

In any case, I suggest you refactor your implementation by using C++11 smart pointers (unique pointers in the example but may be shared according to your application):

```
#include <memory>

struct Node
{
    int myNum;
    std::unique_ptr<<node> pLeftBranch;
    std::unique_ptr<<node> pRightBranch;
};
```

Destructor can simply use default implementation (to be used qt declaration in header file):

```
~Tree() = default;
```

Node *newNode = new Node becomes:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> pNewNode = std::make_unique<Node>();
```